# .Net Core multiple Web Api Authencation

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

i have two .Net Core web api projects(.Net 6)
Project A
Project B
both project are using liteDB database and Vue.js and Electron for bundling

Project A has basic login mechanisum in place.
Project B has no login

Project B internally calls Project A web api through IP Address.

Now the question is i have to implement Authentication mechanism to handle this usecase.
Need your help to suggest best approach to handle this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to implement authentication for both project A and project B?

Comment: only in project A but project B is accessing  project A api calls through IP address. how we will secure that? which is the best authentication approch that can i use here ?

Comment: You could add a third identity provider to provide the token authentication and then let the projcet B use that token to access project A to keep security.

Comment: can you give some more details

Comment: Maybe can refer to Oauth2 client credential flow https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/